# How to use copy value for some cells when a change the value with a list in another cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

When i change the value of column H from ESTOQUE to VENDAS i want the respective line (Range C4:G4) to be paste with its current value and no longer the equation that made the values. This table has hudred of cells so a want to do it automatomaticaly for each line i change the cell to "Vendas".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AumNV.png)

Comment: what you're after is `Worksheet_Change` event. Do a bit of research and let us know what you come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim RowNum As String
    Dim Val As String
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Rename "Sheet1" to your worksheet name
    
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row of column H
        
        Set Rng = .Range("H1:H" & LastRow) 'Set the range from H1 to the lastrow number
        
        If Not Application.Intersect(Rng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then 'the code will only trigger if you change a cell in column H
        
            Val = Target.Value 'assign the value of the cell changed to the variable Val
            RowNum = Target.Row 'assign the row number of the cell changed to the variable RowNum
            
            If Val = "VENDAS" Then 'if the cell value was changed to 'VENDAS' then change from formula to values
    
                Set Rng2 = .Range("C" & RowNum & ":G" & RowNum)
                    
                    Rng2.Value = Rng2.Value
                
            End If
        
        End If
    
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Antonio, 

If this answered your question, can you please mark it as answered? Thank you :)